Why does one sometimes have to sign the baggage tag at the check-in counter?
Why does one sometimes have to sign the baggage tag (picture) at the check-in counter? I wonder what's the point in signing it.

What do you mean? What "tag" are you talking about ? I have never "signed" any baggage thingy at the check in counter.

@Hilmar I added a link to Wikipedia. I had to sign it several times, including when no special mentions such as damaged bag is made on the baggage tag.

Instead of asking about vague generalities, perhaps you would be more likely to get a useful answer if you have the details of an instance of being asked to sign such a tag -- the likes of which I too have never seen in decades of air travel.  What airline were you flying?  What route?

@phoog Thanks, can you give an example where the route matters for the baggage tag signature?

The reverse of a bag tag lists all the various reasons you can be asked to sign it:

They all boil down to getting the passenger to admit, in writing, that there's something unusual about the bag (damage), its contents (fragile, perishable, etc) or how it was checked in (late, rerouted from cabin, etc) and that the airline is not responsible for what happens if the passenger wants to check it in anyway.
I've never experienced or heard of signing a bag tag if nothing is checked, there's literally no point to this if you're not ticking off any of the limited release items.

Thanks! Any point in signing the luggage tag if nothing is checked?

Follow-up questions: What is considered a late check-in in a bag tag?; Why would a late bag check-in the passenger's signature on the bag tag?
